# SQL calculating upper/lowerbound - which way is correct?

Tags: sql, histogram, correctness

I'm pretty new to this and am reading a book on data analysis, i've been stuck on understanding how its calculating the upper and lower bound ranges of order values - I must have been coming back to this page for a while now.

I use excel all the time and thought I might be better typing it out into excel and trying to understand it there, breaking it down into chunks and seeing what I could deduce from that.

I've managed to calculate it correctly in Excel but struggling still to fully grasp it (i've got no formal maths training!!) then I realised for me it's a bit convoluted to get my head round and maybe I could do it a different way.

The below results are the same for both versions of the code (as far as I can see) but my version is easier for me to read and understand.

Can any one tell me why this wouldn't work? If it isn't correct? Any why?

BOOKS VERSION

```
SELECT lowerbound
    ,upperbound
    ,count(*) AS numorders
    ,min(val)
    ,max(val)
FROM (
    SELECT (floor(val / power(10.0, sign(numdigits) * (numdigits - 1))) * power(10.0, sign(numdigits) * (numdigits - 1))) AS lowerbound
        ,(floor(1 + (val / power(10.0, sign(numdigits) * (numdigits - 1)))) * power(10.0, sign(numdigits) * (numdigits - 1))) AS upperbound
        ,o.*
    FROM (
        SELECT (len(cast(floor(abs(totalprice)) AS INT)) * sign(floor(totalprice))) AS numdigits
            ,totalprice AS val
        FROM orders o
        ) o
    ) o
GROUP BY lowerbound
    ,upperbound
ORDER BY lowerbound
```

MY VERSION

```
SELECT lowerbound
    ,upperbound
    ,count(*) AS numorders
    ,min(val)
    ,max(val)
FROM (
    SELECT (left(totalprice,1)*power(10,len(floor(totalprice))-1))/1000 AS lowerbound
        ,((left(totalprice,1)+1)*power(10,len(floor(totalprice))-1))/1000 AS upperbound
        ,totalprice as val
        from orders) o
GROUP BY lowerbound
     ,upperbound
ORDER BY lowerbound
```

Comment: it's easier to understand if you present data before the change and data expected after the change.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you go with Min and Max of a particular column, so you will get the upper bound and lower bound